# binding ComboBox item source

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

In a `DataGrid` (it has its `ItemSource`) my rows has a `ComboBox` and i want to bind its `ItemSource` to a list in `ViewModel`, but i can't. because the `DataContext` is not `ViewModel`, any one have idea to solve this problem?

sample :

`CilyCollection` and `StatusList` are two List in `ViewModel`. and each city has a `Status` property.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="ViewModel">
    <sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CityCollection}">
        <Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
                <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding StatusList}"
                                  Margin="2"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding status,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StatusTemplate}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Putting some sample code/XAML here would help better understand your problem.

Comment: @decyclone : my code is like sample that is now in question.

Answer (score 1):

Try with relative source binding

```
{Binding DataContext.StatusList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have access in your DataTemplate to  CilyCollection item. So you can bind to Status property of city. StatusList is not accessible. To bind StatusList try that:

> < DataTemplate >
>
> < ComboBox ItemsSource="**{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.StatusList}**">
>
> ...

Comment: +1 Because the basic idea is getting there.  However the Path should be Path=DataContext.StatusList